# From and ToJSON in Haskell - a nested data

Tags: haskell

I have this:

```
data Data1 = Data1 { field1 :: Int, field2 :: Int }
data DataMain = DataMain 
    { a :: String 
    , b :: Bool
    , subData :: Data1
    }
```

And JSON

```
{
    a: 'some value',
    b: 'some value2',
    c: 'some value3',
    d: 'some value4',
}
```

And here are the

```
  instance ToJSON DataMain where
  toJSON (DataMain a b subData) =
    object ["a" .= a
      , "b" .= b
      , "c" .= (field1 subData)
      , "d" .= (field2 subData)
    ]
```

How can I do the same thing vise versa?

```
instance FromJSON DataMain where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    DataMain <$> v .: "a"
        <*> v .: "b"
        <*> v .: ?????

  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same applicative notation to parse the nested values like this:

```
instance FromJSON DataMain where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        DataMain <$> v .: "a"
                 <*> v .: "b"
                 <*> (Data1 <$> v .: "c" <*> v .: "d")

    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: by the way, if field1 and field2 were UTCTime, how could I parse it? I tried `Data1 <$> ((read $ v .: "field1")::UTCTime) ...` but failed.

Comment: Declaring them as UTCTime like: `data Data1 = Data1 { field1 :: UTCTime, field2 :: UTCTime }` should make the trick.